# Why this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false ; not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have used `this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` in my `dbcontext` `constructor` to disable lazy loading globally but it's not working.

Comment: What's not working? You are still able to lazy load the entities? Or you got any error?

Comment: I want to stop lazy loading globally, that's why i add this into dbcontext constructor.  But its not working in my . Net core project as it worked in my previous mvc5 applicatio.

Comment: Still able to load entities even i did not use virtual key word.

Comment: Entity Framework attaches related entities that have already been loaded using the same context. Is _that_ what you're seeing? Please read [ask] and explain very explicitly, preferably also with code, what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you set `this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`,and you want to disable it on per-property level.You need to change it to non-virtual.And it will work on related property
For example(StudentClass):

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }
 
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
    }
public class StudentAddress 
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
       
 
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

need to change to:

```
public class Student
        {
            public Student() { }
     
            public int StudentId { get; set; }
            public string StudentName { get; set; }
            public StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
        }
    public class StudentAddress 
        {
            [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
            public int StudentId { get; set; }
            
            public string Address1 { get; set; }
            public string Address2 { get; set; }
           
     
            public Student Student { get; set; }
        }
```

And disabling Lazy Loading means that you will have to manually handle each related property loading.

Comment: Thanks! I have used "this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false" into DbContext Contractor and remove virtual keyword but still i got data for relatives entity.